# How to dynamicly make database insert

Tags: php, database, dynamic

I am trying to insert ID based on what button is clicked dynamicly with php

Cant get it to work..

Here is my code

```
$sql_category = "SELECT * FROM recipedia_categories";
$result_category = $db->query($sql_category);
    while ($row_category = $result_category->fetch_assoc()) {
        $ID_category = $row_category['ID'];
    }

${'category_' . '$row_category["ID"];'} = '';



if( isset( $_POST['category_' . '$row_category["ID"];'] ) ){
            ${'category_' . '$row_category["ID"];'} = $_POST['category_ID'];
        }

$sql = "INSERT INTO recipedia_recipies VALUES ('$category_ID')";

$sql_menu = "SELECT * FROM recipedia_categories ORDER BY category_name ASC";
$result_menu = $db->query($sql_menu);
```

and in html

```
<?php
    while ( $row_menu = $result_menu->fetch_assoc() ) { 
?>
    <option name="category_<?=$row_menu['ID'];?>"><?=$row_menu['category_name'];?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: if you're going to dynamically create variables, consider storing them in an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: Where do you do INSERT? I don't understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: This is a very good readable code. No chance.

Comment: sorry, edited.
$sql = "INSERT INTO recipedia_recipies VALUES ('$category_ID')";

Comment: you are missing the `value` attribute in your `<option>` tag.